# Random number between 1 to 10 using C++

Tags: c++, random

This code is supposed to generate random number between 1 to 10, but it returns 1 every time.

```
int random_integer;
int lowest=1, highest=10;
int range=(highest-lowest)+1;
random_integer = lowest + int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
cout << random_integer << endl;
```

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: seed your random generator : srand((unsigned)time(0));

Comment: C++11 have better [PRNG functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) built-in, including [classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to create numbers in a range. See the example in the last link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
range * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
```

does not do what you think. Introduce some parens:

```
range * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))
```

(Note that this method gives [skewed distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10219355/166749), though.)

Comment: what is the easiest way to get a unskewed distribution between 1-10 .

Comment: @rajat: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx (or use the [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.html) libraries)

Answer (score 11):

If you want a random integer between `lowest` and `highest`, you'd better write

```
random_integer = lowest + rand() % range
```

Answer (score 7):

You're subject to overflow here - `range*rand()`.

Just use what regular folks use: `rand() % 10 + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the solution provided above .
now  to get a different sequence every time you run your program you can use **srand()** function it will provide a seed to   **rand()** function as follows:-

```
srand(time(NULL))  
random_integer = lowest + rand() % range
```

Answer (score 1):

This two are always part of my programs

```
float randf(float lo, float hi) {
    float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
    float diff = hi - lo;
    float r = random * diff;
    return lo + r;
}
int randi(int lo, int hi)
{
    int n = hi - lo + 1;
    int i = rand() % n;
    if (i < 0) i = -i;
    return lo + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that `rand()` returns a value between 0 and 1.

This is not correct, it return value between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.