# How does this expression work: Num*rand() / RAND_MAX?

Tags: c++

How does this expression work?

```
 Num*rand() / RAND_MAX
```

If, for example, I replace the number with `7.7`, it gives me values from `0.` to `7.` (`double`).

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219355/does-n-rand-rand-max-make-a-skewed-random-number-distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) function generates an integer value between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. so `rand()/RAND_MAX` generates real value between `0 and 1`. So in the following code we have
`0 <= val <= n` where `n` can be an integer or a real number.

```
double val = n * rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

Comment: `n` cannot be an integer. Otherwise you'll get 0 or 1 due to integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging onto MrGreen's answer, I have found that when n is an integer, I will get an output of `0` when using `double val = n * rand()/RAND_MAX;`. However, this can be addressed by a slight addition:

`double val = (double) n * rand()/RAND_MAX;`