# Non-reproducible random numbers using `<random>`

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to create a class that produces random numbers for multiple distributions, while keeping them reproducible (by setting an initial seed).

The code seems to work, until I start to use the normal distribution and weird errors surface. These are mainly:

- If I uncomment the `double a = rnd.rnorm(0.0, 1.0);`-line (line 40) (that is if I call `rnorm` before setting a seed), the first random number of the normal distribution does not match anymore, the random numbers afterwards match again
- If I retrieve an odd-number of random numbers from the normal distribution, the normal random numbers are shifted by one (for example by setting line 39 to `int n = 3;`)
- If I do the two things together, the random numbers get shifted by one in the other direction (lead)

Now my question is, what causes this weird behavior? Have I implemented `RNG` in a wrong way? And most importantly, how can I fix it?

## Code

If you want to test the results yourself you can use this http://cpp.sh/9phre

or this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>

// Class to create random numbers 
// Main functions to set the seed: setseed()
// create uniformly distributed values: runif()
// and normally distributed values: rnorm()
class RNG {
public:
    RNG(int seed = (int) time(0)) {
        setseed(seed);
    };
    ~RNG() {};
    void setseed(int newSeed) {
        re.seed(newSeed);
    };

    double runif(double minNum, double maxNum) {
        return dud(re, distUnifDbl::param_type{minNum, maxNum});
    };
    double rnorm(double mu, double sd) {
        return dnd(re, distNormDbl::param_type{mu, sd});
    };

private:
    // take the Mersenne-Twister Engine
    std::mt19937 re {};
    // create the uniform distribution
    using distUnifDbl = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>;
    distUnifDbl dud {};
    // create the normal distribution
    using distNormDbl = std::normal_distribution<double>;
    distNormDbl dnd {};

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    RNG rnd;
    int n = 4; // setting n to an odd number, makes _all_ normal numbers non-reproducible
    //double a = rnd.rnorm(0.0, 1.0); // uncommenting this, makes the _first_ normal number non-reproducible

    printf("Testing some Uniform Numbers\n");
    rnd.setseed(123);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("% 13.10f ", rnd.runif(0.0, 1.0));
    }
    rnd.setseed(123);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("% 13.10f ", rnd.runif(0.0, 1.0));
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nTesting some Normal Numbers\n");
    rnd.setseed(123);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("% 13.10f ", rnd.rnorm(0.0, 1.0));
    }
    rnd.setseed(123);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("% 13.10f ", rnd.rnorm(0.0, 1.0));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

## Results

### Base-case

When setting `n = 4` and leaving `a` commented, I receive the following (which is exactly what I want/need; reproducible "random" numbers):

```
Testing some Uniform Numbers
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089 
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089 

Testing some Normal Numbers
-0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713 
-0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713
```

### Error 1

Now for the errors. Setting `n = 5` (or any odd number), I receive:

```
Testing some Uniform Numbers
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089  0.4911189328 
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089  0.4911189328 

Testing some Normal Numbers
-0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713  1.5213608069 
-0.0482498863 -0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713
```

Which apparently **shifts** all normal numbers by 1. The uniform numbers stay intact (which is good, I guess).

### Error 2

Uncommenting the one line (i.e., calling `rnd.rnorm(0.0, 1.0)` once *before* setting the seeds), leads to the following output (with `n = 4` or any other even number)

```
Testing some Uniform Numbers
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089 
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089 

Testing some Normal Numbers
 0.9761557076 -0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913 
 0.9675940713 -0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913
```

Which apparently breaks **only the first** normal random number, again leaving the uniform numbers ok.

### Error 3

Using the two points together (leaving the line uncommented and setting n to an odd-number), I get this

```
Testing some Uniform Numbers
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089  0.4911189328 
 0.7129553216  0.4284709250  0.6908848514  0.7191503089  0.4911189328 

Testing some Normal Numbers
-0.4553400276 -0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713 
-0.5696096995  1.6958337120  1.1108714913  0.9675940713  1.5213608069
```

Now the second number of normal random numbers gets shifted by one into the other direction (lead).

### System spec

I am using this on an Ubuntu 16.04 and `g++ --version` `g++(Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

## Updates

It doesn't seem to be connected to the specific generator, i.e., replacing the `std::mt19937 re {};` with `std:: linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 48271, 0, 2147483647> re {};`, or with `std::subtract_with_carry_engine<std::uint_fast64_t, 48, 5, 12> re{};` results in the same behavior (but obviously with different numbers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void setseed(int newSeed) {
        re.seed(newSeed);
        dud.reset(); // <---- 
        dnd.reset(); 
    };
```

Distributions have internal state. You need to reset it in order to get the same sequence again.

Comment: In particular, `std::normal_distribution` is often stateful because several common algorithms for generating normally distributed numbers generate two such numbers per run.

Answer (score 3):

If reproducible "random" numbers are something you care about, you should avoid C++ distributions, including `uniform_real_distribution` and `normal_distribution`, and instead rely on your own way to transform the pseudorandom numbers from `mt19937` into the numbers you desire. (For many ways to do so, see my [page on sampling methods](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html). Note that there are [other things to consider](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Ensuring_Reproducibility) when reproducibility is important.)

C++ distribution classes, such as `uniform_real_distribution`, [have no standard implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746092/random-output-different-between-implementations/32746283#32746283). As a result, even if the same seed is passed to these distributions, the sequence of numbers they deliver can vary, *even from run to run*, depending on how these distributions are implemented. Note that it's not the "compiler", the "operating system", or the "architecture" that decides which algorithm is used, but rather the C++ standard library implementation decides. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600866).

On the other hand, random engines such as `mt19937` do have a guaranteed implementation; they will return the same pseudorandom numbers for the same seed, *even across runs*, in all compliant C++ library implementations (including those of different "architectures"). The exception is `default_random_engine`.

See also this question: [Generate the same sequence of random numbers in C++ from a given seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538942/generate-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-in-c-from-a-given-seed).