# Different pseudo random numbers between C++ and Python implementations

Tags: python, c++, random, mersenne-twister

I am trying to reproduce the C++ code into Python 3.6, but the sequence of pseudo random numbers is different in each implementation. The seed are the same on both implementation and as far as I know, both use Mersenne Twister algorithm.

What am I doing wrong?

REMEMBER1: Both codes uses the SAME seed

REMEMBER2: As far as I know, both code uses functions that implemente the SAME algorithm (Mersenne Twister).

C++:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  
    std::mt19937 gen(2);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Python 3.6:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(2)
for i in range(10):
    print(str(rng.randint(0, 62)))
```

Note: `randint` has an exclusive upper bound. That is why I use 61 on C++ code, but 62 on Python code.

Comment: *but the sequence of pseudo random numbers is different in each implementation*  -- Isn't that a feature and not a bug?

Comment: As far as I know, both implementation uses the same algorithm (Mersenne Twister). That way, the results should be the same, once the seed is the same.

Comment: @thc really???? This is the sequence I got only on Python. I don't  understand, but I will triple check :-)

Comment: Yes, I used: `g++ temp.cpp -o temp` then `./temp` output `40 15 45 8 22 43 18 11 40 7`.  Compiler is clang on OS X.

Comment: Mine is g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0 and I really can't figure out why it would give different results anyway, but thank you again.

Comment: The seeding algorithms may be different (integer value to internal state). The original seeding algorithm used by Matsumoto and Nishimura is now considered suboptimal.

Answer (score 4):

You should note that C++'s standard library distributions, including `std::uniform_int_distribution`, use implementation-defined algorithms.  In other words, these implementations may change depending on which C++ library implementation you choose, and those libraries may change those algorithms in the future.  (This is in contrast to C++'s *random engine* classes, such as `std::mt19937`, which do guarantee returning the same pseudorandom values from the same seed.)  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746092/random-output-different-between-implementations/32746283#32746283).

Your best course of action is to implement or find a stable implementation of an RNG algorithm (such as an algorithm I describe in [my article](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Examples_and_Non_Examples)) and implement methods to [transform the random numbers](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html) they deliver.  (There are certain things to keep in mind when choosing an RNG for a particular application; the first article I linked here has more information.)

Comment: and you didn't understood his answer. Basically he says that even though you have used `mt19937` which is well defined the `std::uniform_int_distribution` is not strictly defined, so even in C++ form compiler to compiler you can have different result.

Comment: @carlosOst:  You are using not only `std::mt19937`, but also `std::uniform_int_distribution`, which is implementation-defined -- it can vary from implementation to implementation of the C++ standard library.

Comment: Pretty sure C++ and Python also use different rules for initializing the Mersenne Twister state (which is huge); you may pass `2` as the seed in both cases, but it'll be expanded to completely different internal state, so even without `std::uniform_int_distribution` interfering, the behavior would differ. Not sure if `numpy`'s version is more similar to C++, but [Python's built-in seed expansion algorithm is pretty different from what I can tell](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#L258).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one unique way of getting from a RNG to a single bounded int.  See for example:

http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html

Which has several versions.  Note that C++ and Python take different options here, hence you'll get a different sequence from the "same" RNG and seed.