# std::mersenne_twister_engine and random number generation

Tags: c++, c++11, random

What is the distribution (uniform, poisson, normal, etc.) that is generated if I did the below? The output appears to indicate a uniform distribution. But then, why do we need `std::uniform_int_distribution`?

```
int main()
{
  std::mt19937_64 generator(134);
  std::map<int, int> freq;
  const int size = 100000;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    int r = generator() % size;
    freq[r]++;
  }
  for (auto f : freq) {
    std::cout << std::string(f.second, '*') << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because while `generator()` is an uniform distribution over `[generator.min(), generator.max()]`, `generator() % n` is not a uniform distribution over `[0, n)` (unless `generator.max()` is an exact multiple of `n`, assuming generator.min() == 0).

Let's take an example: `min() == 0`, `max() == 65'535` and `n == 7`.

`gen()` will give numbers in the range `[0, 65'535]` and in this range there are:

- `9'363` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 0`
- `9'363` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 1`
- `9'362` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 2`
- `9'362` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 3`
- `9'362` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 4`
- `9'362` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 5`
- `9'362` numbers such that `gen() % 7 == 6`

If you are wondering where did I get these numbers think of it like this: `65'534` is an exact multiple of `7` (`65'534 = 7 * 9'362`). This means that in `[0, 65'533]` there are exactly `9'362` numbers who map to each of the `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` by doing `gen() % 7`. This leaves `65'534` who maps to `0` and `65'535` who maps to `1`

So you see there is a bias towards `[0, 1]` than to `[2, 6]`, i.e.

- `0` and `1` have a slightly higher chance (`9'363 / 65'536 ≈ 14.28680419921875 %`)‬ of appearing than
- `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `6` (`9'362 / 65'536 ≈ 14.2852783203125‬ %`).

`std::uniformn_distribution` doesn't have this problem and uses some mathematical woodo with possibly getting more random numbers from the generator to achieve a truly uniform distribution.

Comment: Your answer is correct but `generator::max()` is typically one less than a power of 2, not an exact power of 2. Might be a bit confusing to someone trying to understand the workings of the internal source of `std::random_distribution` .

Comment: @doug good point. I will update the answer when I get the time

Answer (score 2):

The random engine `std::mt19937_64` outputs a 64-bit number that behaves like a uniformly distributed random number. Each of the C++ random engines (including those of the `std::mersenne_twister_engine` family) outputs a uniformly-distributed pseudorandom number of a specific size using a specific algorithm.

Specifically, `std::mersenne_twister_engine` meets the [RandomNumberEngine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberEngine) requirement, which in turn meets the [UniformRandomBitGenerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator) requirement; therefore, `std::mersenne_twister_engine` outputs bits that behave like uniformly-distributed random bits.

On the other hand, [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is useful for transforming numbers from random engines into random integers of a user-defined range (say, from 0 through 10). But note that `uniform_int_distribution` and other distributions (unlike random number engines) [can be implemented differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746092/random-output-different-between-implementations/32746283#32746283) from one C++ standard library implementation to another.

Answer (score 1):

`std::mt19937_64` generates a pseudo-random mutually independent sequence of `long long / unsigned long long` numbers. It is supposed to be uniform but I don't know the exact details of the engine, though, it is one of the best discovered engines thus far.

By taking `% n` you get an approximation to pseudo-random uniform distribution over integers `[0, ... ,n]` - but it is inherently inaccurate. Certain numbers have slightly higher chance to occur while others have slightly lower chance depending on `n`. E.g., since `2^64 = 18446744073709551616` so with `n=10000` first `1616` values have a slightly higher chance to occur than the last `10000-1616` values. `std::uniform_distribution` takes care of the inaccuracy by taking a new random number in very rare cases: say, if the number is above `18446744073709550000` for `n=10000` take a new number - it would work. Though, concrete details are up to implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major accomplishments of `<random>` was the separation of distributions from engines.

I see it as similar to Alexander Stepanov's STL, which separated algorithms from containers through the use of iterators. For random numbers I can do an implementation of the Blum-Blum-Shub single bit generator (engine) and it will still work with all the distributions in `<random>`. Or, I can do a simple Linear Congruential Generator, x_{n + 1} = a * x_{n} % m, which when correctly seeded can never generate 0. Again, it will work with all the distributions. Likewise, I can write a new distribution and I don't have to worry about the peculiarities of any engine as long as I only use the interface specified by a UniformRandomBitGenerator.

In general, you should always use a distribution. Also, it is time to retire using '%' for generating random numbers.