# rand() and RAND_MAX giving different values depending upon the datatype

Tags: c, random

Here when I print the value of x its giving zero as output.Whereas when I print y, I am getting correct value(a random number between 0 and 1),the typecasting is the problem it seems.Why do i need to typecast it?

```
double x,y;
x=rand()/RAND_MAX;
printf("X=%f\n",x);
y=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
printf("Y=%f",y);
```

Output

```
X=0.000000
Y=0.546745
```

Comment: Try changing your code to `x = ( rand() % RAND_MAX)`

Comment: Look up integer division.

Comment: Close voters: This should be closed as a duplicate. It's not "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "n \* (rand() / RAND\_MAX)" make a skewed random number distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219355/does-n-rand-rand-max-make-a-skewed-random-number-distribution)

Comment: Why would you ever use `rand()`? Its almost as bad as the [xkcd rng](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: @CodesInChaos random numbers have applications in areas that don't require cryptographically unpredictable sequences.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide an integer by an integer, you get truncating integer division.
So using

```
y = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

is absolutely the right way to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Different types of division yielded different responses.

```
// Integer division
x=rand()/RAND_MAX;

// floating-point division
y=(double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
```

It isn't the a cast is *needed*, but it is one of the ways to insure floating-point division.  I like the last one as it insures the division will be done at least to the precision of `x`, be it `float`, `double` or `long double` without changing code.

```
x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;

x = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;

x = rand()/(1.0*RAND_MAX);

x = rand();
x /= RAND_MAX;
```

BTW, often code needs to generate a number `[0.0 ... 1.0)`: from 0.0 to almost 1.0.

```
x = rand();
x /= RAND_MAX + 1.0;
```