# Generate a random number less than 4 digits but the probability of it having 1, 2, or 3 digits is equal

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I'm currently using `1 + (int)(rand() * 999.0 / RAND_MAX)` to generate a random number between 1 and 999 inclusive but the two and one digit numbers don't occur as often as the three digit numbers.

How can I fix this?

Note that although the original code gives a range of 0 to 999 inclusive, I actually want a range of 1 to 999 inclusive.

Comment: You want a non-uniform distribution where the probability for the 900 3-digit numbers is 1/3 of that for the 9 1 digit numbers, and so on. A simple way to achieve this practically is to pick a random number between 1 and 3, uniformly, then pick that many random digits from 0 to 9.

Comment: @Andrew almost correct ;) The first digit shouldnt be 0 with this approach

Comment: My idea was similar, get a random between 1 and 3 and if its 1, pick another random number 1-9, if it's 2, 10-99 and if it's 3 100-999. That should do it,.

Comment: A small point, but also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219355/does-n-rand-rand-max-make-a-skewed-random-number-distribution: Dividing by `RAND_MAX` does create bias, but probably no worse than `rand()` itself.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I assume the name is a reference to this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-36064659

Comment: To expand on @Bathsheba’s comment — using your method of generating a uniform distribution of numbers has *very* bad statistical properties, don’t use it. Full stop. Some people will argue that “well, it’s actually not too bad for most applications.” Disregard these people. There are trivial ways in C++ of generating much better distributions, there’s no reason whatsoever to settle for something objectively worse.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your observation that one digit numbers don't occur as often as two and three digit numbers is not surprising.

There are only 9 one digit numbers (not including zero), but there are 90 two-digit ones, and 900 three digit ones. So a uniform random number generator will draw numbers in that frequency.

To generate random numbers in the range [1, 999] such that the probability of their having 1, 2, and 3 digits is equal, use your favourite generator to generate a random number `p`, say, in the range [0, 1) (see the new random library functions in C++ to do that), and transform it using `std::pow(1000, p);`.

You should note that the resulting distribution will not be *piecewise-uniform*: that is to say that the probability of drawing a number with a certain number of digits is not the same as the probability of drawing any other number with that number of digits. But it does have a continuous and differentiable cumulative density function which can be important mathematically.

(For the mathematically-inclined, the transformation I'm applying is the *quantile* function of the distribution that the OP needs).

Comment: How exactly does this do what you want? First of all, `pow(base, exp)` works as base^exp, not the other way around. In your case its 1000^p?

Comment: @Vucko Yes. So what is `1000^(1/3)`? What is `1000^(2/3)`? What is `1000^1`?

Comment: I know, but how does this ensure a uniform distribution and also `integer` numbers?

Comment: Anybody considering this solution should note that it's **not** a uniform distribution. You're 6 times more likely to get a 1 than a 9, 9 times more likely to get 10 than 99, and 10 times more likely to get 100 than 999. And you won't get zero at all.

Comment: I'm sorry but this was exactly what I wanted. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Hum. This answer was incorrect until you edited the question. @MarkRansom raised a very good point.

Comment: @FaceyMcFaceFace then you might also be interested in [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).

Answer (score 20):

You can also use if statements, which are a little bit faster:

```
    int m=rand();
    if(m%3+1==3)
        z=(int)rand()%900+100;
    else if(m%3+1==2)
        z=(int)rand()%90+10;
    else if(m%3+1==1)
        z=(int)rand()%10;
```

The `clock()` difference for 100,000,000 repeats is:

```
t_pow: 23912
t_if: 6640
```

Test code using clock ticks for performance distribution -
[IF](https://ideone.com/IK3hjp), 
[POW](https://ideone.com/aD3Naw)

Difference in distribution between if and pow variant: [Plot in wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+30*x%2BH%28x-1%2F3%29*%28240*x-%281%2F3*240%29%29%2BH%28x-2%2F3%29*%282430*x-%282%2F3*2430%29%29,+g%28x%29%3D1000%5Ex+,+x%3D0..1)

Comment: If I'm reading that right, you're generating random numbers in the range of (0-9), (10-19), (100-199)....  I think your first two mods need to be 900 and 90, not 100 and 10.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that mistake, I will edit it.

Comment: upvoted. Sorry I had the incorrect question. I've changed it a bit. I don't want the number zero.

Comment: Your answer is biased. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator

Comment: This is a good answer if you do desire piecewise uniformity. But over-consumption of random numbers can create problems with some generators (e.g. Sobol). Just be aware of this. And note that taking a modulus of `rand()` tends to create bias, particularly for a small modulus. Do test that this has the required statistical properties.

Comment: @Bathsheba actually the smaller the modulus is compared to `RAND_MAX`, the lower the bias - the worst case is `% RAND_MAX`, where `0` is *twice* as likely to occur as any other number. And if the modulus is a power of 2, for most (all?) implementations of `rand` the bias is eliminated completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one statement that uses 2 randoms. Multiplies the first by 10 ** second. The second is 1, 2 or 3. Here it is as an Excel formula:

```
=Int(Rand()*10^(int(Rand()*3)+1))
```

Comment: A good answer when you have a floating-point random number generator. Unfortunately C/C++'s `rand` isn't one of them. And @FaceyMcFaceFace, yes it *does* allow zero, if the first `rand` returns zero or very close to it. And for that reason it's also slightly biased to the lower numbers; 0-9 will appear more than 1/3 of the time.

Comment: @mark ransom Yes, you're right. I realised the *10 and *100 options could still allow for lower numbers after I posted it. 0-9 can result from all 3 options and 10-99 can also result from the *100 option so there's an elevated chance of those too. Yes, in principle it can produce zero too. Didn't realise that about c++ Rand, my only experience c++ it is in Arduino and I thought it was a limitation of the hardware not the language itself.

Comment: @Lefty `rand` is extremely old and primitive. C++ recently added more modern random number capabilities, see for example [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm pretty old and primitive myself so am well versed in using floating point random numbers on virtually every platform I've used. Most of the time, you're just manipulating them into Ints anyway. The Arduino library I've been playing with lately has it's own Int rand function which suits my purposes there - but I never realised that C++ itself doesn't allow for them.