# How to generate 12 digit random number in C?

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to generate 12 digit random numbers in C, but it's always generating  10 digit numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   long r = rand();
   r = r*100;
   printf("%ld",r);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You are aware that a 12 digit number doesn't fit into 32 bits, so start checking the length of the `long` type on your platform.

Comment: The code is described above.

Comment: Sigh... if the `long` type a 32 bits (which is the case on many platforms), then you cannot fit a 12 digit number into a `long`. What platform are you on and which compiler do you use ?

Comment: I'm using gcc Compiler @Michael Walz

Comment: It is *very* strange that code shown is "always generating 10 digit number"... I'd expect value string from 100 and up (3-12 digits), always ending in 00 (which is not very random).

Comment: @kulst gcc on Windows also follow Windows convention and use 32-bit `long`. On 32-bit Linux `long` is also a 32-bit type. Please state what platform you're on

Comment: I use linux platform @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: @kulst as I said, it's different on 32 and 64-bit Linux

Answer (score 2):

`rand()`  returns an `int` value in the range of `[0...RAND_MAX]`

Based on the C spec, `RAND_MAX >= 32767` and `RAND_MAX <= INT_MAX`.

Call `rand()` multiple times to create a wide value

---

```
unsigned long long rand_atleast12digit(void) {
  unsigned long long r = rand();
  #if RAND_MAX >= 999999999999
  #elif RAND_MAX >= 999999
    r *= RAND_MAX + 1ull;
    r += rand();
  #else
    r *= RAND_MAX + 1ull;
    r += rand();
    r *= RAND_MAX + 1ull;
    r += rand();
  #endif
  return r;
}
```

The above returns a number if the range of 0 to *at least* 999,999,999,999.  To reduce that to only that range, code could use `return r % 1000000000000;`.

---

Using `%` likely does not create an balanced distribution of random numbers. Other posts address details of how to cope with that like [this good one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219422/2410359) incorporated as follows.

```
#if RAND_MAX >= 999999999999
  #define R12DIGIT_DIVISOR (RAND_MAX/1000000000000)
#elif RAND_MAX >= 999999
  #define RAND_MAX_P1  (RAND_MAX+1LLU)
  #define R12DIGIT_DIVISOR ((RAND_MAX_P1*RAND_MAX_P1-1)/1000000000000)
#else
  #define RAND_MAX_P1  (RAND_MAX+1LLU)
  #define R12DIGIT_DIVISOR  ((RAND_MAX_P1*RAND_MAX_P1*RAND_MAX_P1-1)/1000000000000)
#endif

unsigned long long rand_12digit(void) {
    unsigned long long retval;
    do { 
        retval = rand_atleast12digit() / R12DIGIT_DIVISOR;
    } while (retval == 1000000000000);
    return retval;
}
```

Note that the quality of `rand()` is not well defined, so repeated calls may not provide high *quality* results.

---

OP's code fails if `long` is 32-bit as it lacks range for a 12 decimal digit values.  [@Michael Walz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898348/michael-walz)

If `long` is wide enough, `*100` will always make the least 2 decimal digits `00` - not very random.   [@Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360652/how-to-generate-12-digit-random-number-in-c/40363112#comment67975130_40360652)

```
long r = rand();
r = r*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of [rand is `int`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), which means you can't get a 12 digit number directly from it.

If you need value that is always 12 digits you need to make sure values fit in particular range.

Sample below assumes that you need just some of the numbers to be 12 digits - you just need 8 extra bits - so shifting and OR'ing results would produce number in 0x7fffffffff-0 range that would often result up to 12 digit output when printed as decimal:

```
r = rand();
r = (r << 8) | rand();
```

PS: Make sure the variable that will store the result is big enough to store the 12 digit number.

Comment: The unsigned long can go up to 4,294,967,295. and long to 2,147,483,647, which are 10 digit numbers. You need to "construct" yourself a 12 digit number, since your maximum result can go just up to 10 digits (limited by the return type of the rand function).

Comment: `(r << 8) | rand();` is _poor_ solution to extend the `rand()` range as it increases the chances for 1 bits dramatically.  Better to use `(r << 8) ^ rand();`.  Also unless `r` is a wider type than 32-bit, this approach will not work.

Comment: My focuse was on what is the cause of the problem and suggesting a way to resolve it. Thank you for the suggestion, will take it in mind.

Comment: @Gnqz `unsigned long can go up to 4,294,967,295. and long to 2,147,483,647` incorrect. C standard [doesn't state that `long` must be 32 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/995714). It depends on compiler implementation. Moreover `int` **can** have more than 32 bits so it can definitely store a 12-digit number. Again it also depends on compiler implementation

Comment: but 
r = rand();
r = (r << 8) ^ rand();
this code doesn't generate different number always generates 462669366470 this number.

Comment: another problem of yours is that you're assuming `RAND_MAX` has 32 bits. No, on Windows it's often 15 bits and on Linux it's 31 bits

Comment: so the 32th bit will always be zero in this case

Comment: your code also doesn't make sure that the result will always be less than 1e12 because a 40-bit number definitely can have 13 digits

Answer (score 0):

My simple way to generate random strings or numbers is :

```
static char *ws_generate_token(size_t length) {

    static char charset[] = "1234567890"; // generate numbers only
    //static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; to generate random string
    char *randomString = NULL;

    if (length) {
        randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));

        if (randomString) {
            for (int n = 0; n < length; n++) {
                int key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset) -1);
                randomString[n] = charset[key];
            }

            randomString[length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return randomString;
}
```

**Explain the code**

1. Create an array of chars which will contains (numbers, alphabets ...etc)
2. Generate a random number between [0, array length], let's name it X.
3. Get the character at random X position in the array of chars.
4. finally, add this character to the sequence of strings (or numbers) you want to have in return.

*How to use it ?*

```
#define TOKEN_LENGTH      12
char *token;

token = ws_generate_token(TOKEN_LENGTH);
```

*conversion from string to int*

```
int token_int = atol(token);
```

*dont forget !*

```
free(token); // free the memory when you finish
```

Comment: Ok, but the question is about generating 12-digits *numbers*, not strings. Also please note that an `int` might not be wide enough to store such numbers. You are proposing to use `atol` to convert the string, but what would be the returned numbers when the inputs are like `"z2"`, `"42b"` or  `"nope"`?

Comment: Easy, put numbers only in the 'charset'  this will generate string of numbers (ex: "127653986343")  then  use atol to convert it to int.

Answer (score -3):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i, n;
   time_t t;

   n = 5;

   /* Intializes random number generator int range */
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));

   /* Print 5 random numbers from 50 to back
   for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   {
      printf("%d\n", rand() % 50);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: what are you doing? And how is `rand() % 50` printing a number from 0 to 32767?

Comment: rand will print number with the different of five from where u want it to back or forward like above (50,45,40,35....)

Comment: how is it relevant to the OP's question? your program doesn't even generate numbers >= 50