# Is this random integer function acceptable for generating passwords?

Tags: javascript, random

I've been goofing around with random numbers a lot recently and have usually just used Math.Random as I've had no need to use something more secure, however I figured it would be useful to learn stuff like this and I was wondering how secure / practical this function is and some improvements I could implement.

```
function random_number(max) {
    let buffer=new ArrayBuffer(8);
    let ints=new Int8Array(buffer);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(ints);
    ints[7]=64-1;
    ints[6]|=0xf0;
    let float=new DataView(buffer).getFloat64(0,true)-1;
    return Math.floor(float*Math.floor(max+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.

What you're effectively doing (via a cast of binary data to a floating point value) is calculating `floor(max * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0))` (with `RAND_MAX` equal to 2<sup>52</sup>−1). This will always result in a skewed distribution unless `max` is a factor of `RAND_MAX+1`, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219422/1679849).

This is quite easy to demonstrate:

```js
function random_number(max) {
    let buffer=new ArrayBuffer(8);
    let ints=new Int8Array(buffer);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(ints);
    ints[7]=64-1;
    ints[6]|=0xf0;
    let float=new DataView(buffer).getFloat64(0,true)-1;
    return Math.floor(float*Math.floor(max+1));
}

function check_skew() {
    var m = Math.floor(Math.pow(2,52) * 2 / 3);
    var o = [0,0];
    var ns = 100000;
    for (i=0; i<ns; i++) o[random_number(m)&1]++; o;
    console.log("Out of "+ns+" random numbers, "+o[0]*100/ns+
                "% were even and "+o[1]*100/ns+"% were odd.");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check_skew()">Click this button a few times and check the results</button>
```

The correct way to obtain a random integer over a specified range is to start with a uniform random number whose bit length is at least as long as that of `max`. Discard the higher bits, and return the result if it is less than or equal to `max`. Otherwise repeat the process.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
function rand_int(max) {
    // Returns a uniform random integer from 0 to max (inclusive)
    var mask = 1;
    var crypto = window.crypto;
    max = Math.floor(max);

    if (!crypto) throw "window.crypto undefined";
    if (max < 1) throw "max value too small";
    if (max > 0xffffffff) throw "max value too large";

    // Generate binary mask (all 1)
    while (mask < max) mask = (mask << 1) | 1;

    // Now generate random values until one is within range
    var r = new Int32Array(1);
    do {
        crypto.getRandomValues(r);
        r[0] &= mask;
    } while (r[0] > max);
    return r[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know too much about this.

Comment: EDIT: I noticed that you use the (variable?) rval instead of directly using r, is this an accident or is there a reason I should add "var rval = r"

Comment: @fgorov Oops, you're right. Should have been `r`, not `rval`!